# Modify Google Calendar recurring Event using API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API to create/modify recurring events

for e.g. - there is an event (Say ABC) having recurring events on Monday, Wednesday & Thursday till 31st January 2021 (**say 30 occurrences**). While creating this event, I calculated number of US holidays coming in this schedule (**suppose 1**) and increased the `COUNT` by that number (**which will be now 31**) and later delete those instances which were occurring those holidays (like 26th Nov, 27th Nov, 24th December etc). Everything works fine till here.

Now I've to add an attendee to this event which I'm able to do by sending a PATCH request ([reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)) with updated attendees list. This updates the attendees list but it undo's the instances that I deleted. I want recurring event to remain as it is.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- After succesfully deleting the spare event instances, you should be able to add invitees to the non-deleted instance by specifying the `recurringEventId` as `eventId`
- If for whatever reason this is not working as intended you can perform the following workaround:

  - Use the method [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) with the option `showDeleted`:`false` to retrieve the `ids` of all not deleted event recurrences
  - Use the method `Events: patch` in a loop specifying as `eventId` all single event ids retrieved in the step above

**Mind:**

While the `recurringEventId` should look something like `qgthctibhb7755q02hnm3cdb3s`, the id of each single instance should look something like `qgthctibhb7755q02hnm3cdb3s_20201104` (the date is included in the id)

Comment: you mean that I should PATCH each instance individually?

Comment: As a workaround. To be honest, I do not understand why you have problems patching the whole event series - I cannot reproduce your problem of deleted events comind back. Mind that if you performed some modificaiton to the recurent event - the recurringEventId might have changed - make sure to use the updated recurringEventId.